# Needing to render a single field from a model in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Puzzling over a way to render a single field from an ActiveRecord_Relation collection retrieved from our application's Task model:

```
results = Task.all
```

`Task.all` returns an ActiveRecord_Relation object containing key-value pairs representing the fields of the db and their corresponding values, eg:

```
[#<Task:0x007ff7af13b628
  id: 1,
  name: "x_task_name",
  project_id: 1
 ..., etc.
]
```

This results in multiple fields (id, project name, task name) rendering in the view using the `index` method:

```
def index
  @task_names = Task.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @task_names}
  end
end
```

Which is rendered to the view using haml:

```
%table#task_activity_report.display
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Task Name
  %tbody
    = render @task_names
```

However, all I want to render right now is the Task relation's `name` field. I've tried changing out my query on the Task model: `Task.all` with `Task.pluck(:name)`. This effectively results in an array containing the *values* of each task name (exactly as noted in the docs), however, my suspicion is that the object I need to pass to the view to have it render successfully should look more like the ActiveRecord_Relation:

```
[name: "a_task_name", name: "b_task_name", name: "c_task_name", ...n ]
```

Is there a query I can use that will return the desired relation, or should I be using Ruby to process the results of using pluck, iterating over the array and adding a `name` key to each string-typed element?

Coming to Ruby from a mostly JavaScript background. I need to work with Ruby on Rails at my first dev job.

Comment: Have you tried: results = Task.select('id, name')

Comment: I _**did**_ actually initially make use of a very similar `#select` query to get results in-line with what I was looking for, however, trying to pass these results through to render in the view actually violated some other logic of the application having to do with `:name` being "delegated" to `:project` in the model: `delegate :name, ...etc., :to => :project`.

Comment: While your response provides an answer correctly returning the desired data in my console, other influencing application logic plays a role here not explicitly stated in my question. I would say there are a few different ways of approaching this problem which Chris Heald really helped me understand below. Thank you for your input! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `#pluck` will do what's asked in the question. That's roughly equivalent to just running `select fieldname from tablename`, and getting the results as a list of primitives.

```
# Controller
@task_names = Task.all.pluck(:name)

# View
%td=@task_names.join(", ")
```

Longer answer:

The `ActiveRecord::Relation` object is a proxy for a query. When you materialize it, it runs the query and then creates an `Array` of `Task` instances, one per row returned, with their attributes matching the columns from each row. These Task instances are themselves subclasses of `ActiveRecord::Base`. This isn't critical to the answer, but it may help your understanding of the structure.

Since you have a list of `Task` objects, and `ActiveRecord::Base` instances expose their fields as instance methods, one Ruby-ish way to do this would be use `#all` to fetch an `Array` of `Task` instances, then Array#each to loop through the array, and then you would render out the desired field from each:

```
# Controller
@tasks = Task.all

#View

%tbody
- @tasks.each do |task|
    %tr
      %td=task.name
```

The reason you might want to do it this way is that you might find yourself wanting additional fields from your tasks. Consider if you wanted the name and due date:

```
%tbody
- @tasks.each do |task|
    %tr
      %td=task.name
      %td=task.due_date
```

Rather than having to pluck out a list of values for each field, you can retrieve a list of Task objects, and interact with those instead.

Alternately, if you already have a list of Task objects and wanted to collect all the values for a particular field out of them, you would use [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
@tasks = Task.all
@task_names = @tasks.map(&:name)
```

If you did genuinely want an array of Hashes with the key `:name` and the value given, you would do something like:

```
@task_names = Task.pluck(:name).map {|n| {name: n} }
```

In Rails views, `render` is used to invoke a partial, though, so I suspect you may be wanting to invoke `render "some_partial", collection: @tasks`. If this is the case, then yes, you'll want your collection to be an array of Task objects, if the partial you're rendering expects a list of Task objects.

See [the documentation on partials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for a more complete explanation.

You may need to define the desired output more clearly to get a more specific answer, but there are many ways to get to the desired slicing of the data. Understanding how ActiveRecord instances operate, and how they're typically used in views will be important to understanding how to get what you want.

Comment: While I was able to get interesting and revealing results to render from each of these examples, it was the second "Ruby-ish" snippet here which allowed me to circumspect the other influencing application logic and render exactly the data as intended.

Comment: Otherwise, the other examples, links, and rationale provided here are really helping me extend my understanding of Rails queries and what Ruby is capable of, esp. its utility for working with data in the view.

Comment: _**THANK YOU SO MUCH**_ for taking the time to write this up. Your response definitely helped me bring some critical threads together in my previously muddled thinking about this problem and about `ActiveRecord_Relation` objects in general. Literally, this learning moment is among the best things that's happened to me this week!

Comment: So happy that it helped clear some things up for you! :D